# INDEX( ,MATCH()) combination returns #VALUE error in data formatted as TABLE

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two data sets (two sheets in the same workbook) where I need to locate entries from one in the other one. Both sets are formatted as a Table and I am using an `INDEX(MATCH())` combination to match entries. If a match is found, values from one of the fields in **Dataset1** should appear in an added column of the **Dataset2**. That way I know there is a match, I don't really care about the value returned.

Unfortunately, I do not have any `uniqueID` to match on so I have to use a combination of two fields in each of the tables to try and produce matches. Fields are `[@Name]` and `[@Surname]`, which is less then ideal in Croatian language, since the name **Adis Terzic** will obviously not match **Adis Terzić**.

**The problem**

- added column (field) in **Dataset2** does not show any values returned from the **Dataset1** but rather all it shows is a `#VALUE` error.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

My syntax is along the following lines:

```
=INDEX(Table1[@Field4],MATCH(Table1[@Name trim]&Table1[Surname trim], Table2[Name]&Table2[Last name], 0))
```

[Here is an example workbook (Google Drive).](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E1SJPDiMvURip9mPZcNNtkRyWdm-nwPv/view?usp=sharing)

- Dataset1 (Table1) has about 28000 rows and 16 columns;
- Dataset2 (Table2) has about 24000 rows and 7 columns;

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider adding a helper column, instead of making the formula combine the fields. The formula is easier to manage, and you could more easily compare name differences like you mentioned above.

I'd add a helper column to combine your names. Since you're using a table, it could just be Column titled "NameLookup" =([Fname] & "" & [Lname])

Then your index match would look like

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[@Field4],MATCH(Table1[NameLookup],Table2[NameLookup],0),"Not Found")
```

I actually have a similar sheet where I need to compare two lists of names. I face the challenge of dealing with middle initials and suffixes (like jr, sr, III, etc). Not to mention extra spaces...
Here's a snapshot of how I broke it down with helper columns:
[image]
Here's how it all works:
"Check Full Name" is a COUNTIF comparing the full name to the list on the second sheet. If it finds a match, I'm good.
"First name, Middle, Last Name, No Suffix" - these are all variations on a TRIM formula to break the name up.

First Name:
`=LEFT([@NAME],SEARCH(" ",[@NAME]))`

Middle:
`=IFERROR(MID([@NAME],SEARCH(" ",[@NAME],1)+1,SEARCH(" ",[@NAME],SEARCH(" ",[@NAME],1)+1)-SEARCH(" ",[@NAME],1)),"")`

Last Name:
`=IFERROR(RIGHT([NAME],LEN([NAME])-SEARCH(" ",[NAME],SEARCH(" ",[NAME],SEARCH(" ",[NAME])+1))),RIGHT([@NAME],LEN([@NAME])-FIND(" ",[@NAME],1)))`

No Suffix:
`=IFERROR(LEFT([@[Last Name]],FIND(" ",[@[Last Name]])-1),"")`

Best guess is a column I use to help me find a close match to the name:

```
=IFERROR(IF([@[Check Full Name]]=0,INDEX(Marketing[NAME],MATCH([@DrillFirstNoSfx],Marketing[MarketFirstNoSfx],0)),""), "Not Found")
```

I use conditional formatting on the NAME cell to easily determine if there's a match or not. Black text (Check Full Name > 0), Red Text means no match at all, Yellow text means there's a close match (value in the Best Guess column).

Hope some of this helps point you in the direction of a solution!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Enter this formula in the first cell of the `New1` column of Table 2, then fill right and down.

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(($A$28:$A$30=$J28)*($B$28:$B$30=$K28)),C$28:C$30),"No Match")
```

Adjust the data range as necessary.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Is there a way to write this in a more "dynamic" way, to be able to add data to both tables, as it eveolves? I just learned how to work with querries and fields so would prefer to stick with this. If I use this VLOOKUP method I'm gonna have to keep track of ranges all the time :)

Comment: If you can handle the VBA code I can suggest you!